# Laravel API returns a meta tag with the json response

Tags: json, laravel, api, meta-tags, jsonresponse

My api keeps returning this meta tag within  my json response :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1256" />
```

What I'm doing is creating a new user then send the access token and token info:

```
if (\Auth::attempt(['email' => $user->email, 'password' => $request->password])) {
            return Auth::user()->createToken('mobileUser', []);
        }
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Invalid username or Password']);
```

The api works just fine but the response is wrong.. when theres an error, it doesn't send the meta tag.. I tried to make it like this

```
return response()->json(Auth::user()->createToken('mobileUser', []));
```

But I got the same result..
Any  reason why I keep getting this?

Comment: do you set `Accept: application/json` in your request's header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the SMS function was causing this tag to appear... You have to edit it like this :

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "your_url_SMS_service_here");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_exec($ch);
```

If you encounter this tag, there should be a function behind the return causing that. Look for it and  fix it

Answer (score 0):

```
if(Auth::attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')])){ 

     $user = Auth::user(); 
     $success['token'] =  $user->createToken(config('name'))->accessToken; 
     return response()->json(['success' => $success], $this->successStatus); 

} else{ 

     return response()->json(['error'=>'Unauthorised'], 401); 

}
```